# How to sort List<? extends T>

Tags: java

I have a list

```
List<? extends T> generics;
```

how can we sort this ?  Is it possible to compare subclass objects on Comparator implementation?

Thanks

Comment: Collections.sort(generics)?

Comment: How would you like to compare the objects in the list?

Comment: I would like to know what are the possible ways to do comparison in our comparator code if that list have apples or oranges or pears of type Fruit.

Answer (score 2):

See [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), where `T` must `implements Comparable<T>`

However I would bound `T` to a known base class that has `final` `compareTo` to ensure that when comparing apples to pears you treat them both as fruit

**EDIT**:
From your comment you could go with the suggestion above, but an alternative to implementing [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) would be to write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Either way, if you have apples, pears or oranges then I would recommend making an abstract class Fruit, and implement Comparable/Comparator in terms of Fruit - this is the only sensible way to compare apples and pears etc - by attributes known to be common to all subclasses.

Example code:

```
public abstract class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {

    public abstract String getName();

    public abstract Integer getWeightInGrams();

    @Override
    public final int compareTo(Fruit other)
    {
        return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
    }
}

public class Orange extends Fruit {

    private final Integer weightInGrams;

    public Orange(int weightInGrams)
    {
        this.weightInGrams = weightInGrams;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Orange";
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getWeightInGrams()
    {
        return weightInGrams;
    }
}


//Or just using comparators (in which case Fruit does not need to implement Comparable):

public class FruitWeightComparator implements Comparator<Fruit> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2)
    {
        return o1.getWeightInGrams().compareTo(o2.getWeightInGrams());
    }
}


public class FruitNameComparator implements Comparator<Fruit> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2)
    {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is asked on an interview. They didn't provide details whether T implements Comparable or not.  List may have apples or pears or oranges. How could we write comparator code for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. So if we implement Comparator ,we can check only base class variables. Can we do like this for subclass     if(o1 instance of Apple  && o2 instance of Apple){                                                            return compare o1.get().compareTo(o2.get)                                                      }

Comment: Do you have a real use-case here?  Not sure I understand what you would do when o1 instanceof Apple && o2 instanceof Banana.  Regardless you want to avoid type introspection (i.e. different behaviour based on type received).

Comment: Actually I try to figure out is there any way to sort out via subclass variables when we don't know the subclass details in the list. I mean if we get a List<? extends T> and T doesn't implements comparable, in that case how we can sort the list? what are the possibilities?

Comment: This doesn't make sense - you cannot compare Apples & Pears in terms of features that are only present in Apples.   If you can provide a genuine use-case, we can may be find a solution, but a generic "how do I compare Apples & Pears?" question, will only get a generic/common-sense answer "You cannot".   Sorry

Answer (score 0):

> how can we sort this ?

All elements must be mutually comparable i.e. `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`. It means elements of type `T` is comparable not only to T but also comparable to elements of type `super to T`.

If you do not specify comparator then in that case list will be sorted into ascending order using natural ordering. In your case the class would be having multiple fields and using a custom comparator makes sense.

> Is it possible to compare subclass objects on Comparator
>   implementation?

Yes it is. If you specify `<T extends Comparable<T>>` then only elements of type `T` are mutually comparable but if you use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` then elements of super class also gets included.

Comment: Can you pls share sample code to understand more about your second explanation